# How to reencode different files with ffmpeg to 16:9 or 4:3 pixel size?

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

I have a big bunch of videofiles that are anamorphic.

I need to reencode them for use in a videoplayer that is not able to stretch pixels and therefore ignores aspect ratio metadata.

Is there an easy option on ffmpeg to reencode the videos to either 16:9 or 4:3 pixel size so I can create a script for running through my few hundred files?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49120799/

Comment: Thx. So code for 16:9 would be: 
```
    ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
           -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih:eval=frame,setsar=1,\
                pad=max(iw\,ih*(16/9)):ow/(16/9):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:eval=frame" \
           -aspect 16:9  -o output.mkv
```
and for 4/3

```
    ffmpeg -i input.mkv \
           -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih:eval=frame,setsar=1,\
                pad=max(iw\,ih*(4/3)):ow/(4/3):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:eval=frame" \
           -aspect 4:3  -o output.mkv
```
What does the eval=frame stand for? Is is the right option for video, as the linked question refers to single pictures?